# Change Option Button selection in Userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have created a vba to change the options in Userform and partially succeeded. But am unable to change the data for Option button and Checkbox. I get a message as"False" in that row. Please help me out!

```
Private Sub cmdupdate_Click() 
    If Me.cmbslno.Value = "" Then 
        MsgBox "SL No Can Not be Blank!", vbExclamation, "SL No" 
        Exit Sub 
    End If 

    SLNo = Me.cmbslno.Value Sheets("Data").Select 

    Dim rowselect As Double 
    rowselect = Me.cmbslno.Value 
    rowselect = rowselect + 3 
    Rows(rowselect).Select 
    Cells(rowselect, 2) = Me.TextEmpCode.Value 
    Cells(rowselect, 3) = Me.TextEmpName.Value 
    **Cells(rowselect, 5) = Me.Option1.Value 
    Cells(rowselect, 5) = Me.Option2.Value 
    Cells(rowselect, 5) = Me.Option3.Value** 
    Cells(rowselect, 17) = Me.TextBox1.Value 
    Cells(rowselect, 18) = Me.TextBox2.Value 
    Cells(rowselect, 19) = Me.TextBox3.Value
    Cells(rowselect, 20) = Me.TextIncome.Value 
End Sub
```

Comment: *I get a message as"False" in that row.* - what exactly do you get? Can you put a screenshot?

Comment: When I change the Option button from Option 1 to Option 2 in Userform, It is not getting updated in the Excel sheet.

Comment: Do you click on `cmdupdate` after the change?

Comment: Yes I do, but other contents in text box changes but not the Radio button and the check box

Comment: You realize that you have given column `5` three times?

Comment: **Cells(rowselect, 5) = Me.Option1.Value 
    Cells(rowselect, 5) = Me.Option2.Value 
    Cells(rowselect, 5) = Me.Option3.Value**

Comment: You say you have created "vba to change the options in Userform", but your code does the exact opposite: inserts data (or "options") from the userform into the document!?

Comment: yes it bcos the content of the 3 radio button option Ex: A, B, C are in the same row in excel. So When I fill the Userform with Option A and need to amend it to B, The option should be changed in the same row in excel sheet

Comment: So basically you're trying to save the user selections ("options") from userform in the document so that the userform comes preconfigured with the last used set of options the next time it is initialized?

Comment: Yes, not preconfigured, but you update it as Pending and once the task is completed, Radio Button Pending to be changed to "Completed" and shld reflect .

Comment: say U check box as Pending and it is updated in A5. Now in userform check box as complete once task is completed and this shld change as Completed in A5

Comment: Check out Vincent G's answer below  which is exactly what I'd do as well. And the next time you post you might might consider wording your question a bit better. It wasn't clear from the outset exactly what the problem was and what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Apologies and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to put "Option 1", "Option 2" or "Option 3" in the cell?

Change the following:

```
Cells(rowselect, 5) = Me.Option1.Value 
Cells(rowselect, 5) = Me.Option2.Value 
Cells(rowselect, 5) = Me.Option3.Value
```

To

```
Cells(rowselect, 5) = IIf(Me.Option1.Value, "Option 1", IIf(Me.Option2.Value, "Option 2", "Option 3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check like this:

```
Cells(rowselect, 21) = Me.Option1.Value 
Cells(rowselect, 22) = Me.Option2.Value 
Cells(rowselect, 23) = Me.Option3.Value
```

The column `5` is given 3 times, they are overlapping each time.

Comment: If i do this, the data is reflected in 21 row. but need that in the 5th row where the Options like A to be changed to B

Comment: @ChandrasekarR - yes. And on `22` and on `23`. I have written these to show you that in your code your are using row `5` 3 times. Thus only the last update stays.

Comment: oh ok, say U check box as Pending and it is updated in A5. Now in userform check box as complete once task is completed and this shld change as Completed in A5